# How to generate an update package to deploy in Development devices (Surfaces and Phones)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, uwp

For Windows Universal Apps, would it possible to deploy an app package as an updation package in a Phone or Surface rather than deploying it as a clean package? Similar to how the update process works when the user tries to download an update from store?

I tried to deploy using Powershell for Surface and Deployment utility for mobiles. But both seems to re-install the app in the devices rather than updating it.

I would like to verify how the app behaves when updated rather than being re-installed.

Any suggestions on how to perform this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to sideload an application package that simulates a store update. The store *will* update the package just by downloading the block level changes to your package, but there are no tools to do that locally.

One way to verify app update behavior is to upload the updated application as a [flight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/publish/package-flights), then sideload the original package (before the update), and try to update the package with the flight (directly from the store). When you are confident the behavior is as desired, you can then release the flight to all of your customers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Daniel. We would be able to do upgrade using the Deployment Commandline tool. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn632395.aspx. Is there a way to get the app id of an app through any means, apart from finding it in App Manifest?

Comment: You can get the package full name of all installed applications by using the Get-AppxPackage powershell command. If you try to get it from an app that is not already installed, then your best bet is to inspect the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel. I was able to get the GUID from Windows Phone 8.1 store, by sharing the app.